# If $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$ does $f^{(n)}(x) = g^{(n)}(x)$ for all n?

Tags: calculus

My question is, for two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, if we know that on some interval of the real line (would also be interested if this was true for some area on the complex plane) that $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$, does $f^{(n)}(x) = g^{(n)}(x)$ on the same plane for all positive integers?

**Edit** it seems like the consensus is that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same function if they are pointwise equal on the domain. Does the domain need any properties for that to be true?

Comment: If the functions are identical then all their derivatives are, as well, so you don't need the extra hypothesis about $f'$.

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ on an *interval*, then necessarily $f^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$ on the same interval (to the extent that the derivatives exist).

Comment: Does the interval need to have certain properties? What about when the interval is a single point, or disconnected points?

Comment: This works for open intervals. Things can go wrong at boundary points. So, as you guessed, single points cause problems. I suggest you look at tools from real analysis to deal with odd/special cases.

Comment: @kleineg, I think user72694 and I were both assuming that "interval" had its common meaning of $x$'s lying between two *distinct* points.

Comment: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (analytically speaking) are the same function _on that domain_ if they're identical at each point of the domain; this is essentially the very definition of function in this context.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good point. I may have been mixing terminology, I guess my question was more generally about domains. Which could be open or closed (or both).

Comment: @Julien That seems like the beginning to exactly the answer I was wondering about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are defined on the same domain $X$ and $f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$ for all $x\in X$, then $f = g$ and the two objects $f$ and $g$ are indistinguishable. No knowledge of the derivative has been used to establish this yet.

Therefore, if $f^\left(n\right)$ exists at $x \in X$, it must be equal to $g^\left(n\right)$ at $x$.

If the two functions are not defined on the same domain but the restrictions $f\mid_X$ and $g\mid_X$ have the above property, then you can use the same argument above with $h\equiv f\mid_X$ and $i \equiv g\mid_X$ (at least on the interior).